# Horizontal recyclerview snap to center while previous/next items are visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to achieve this.
[image: first item of recyclerview with next item visible]
[image: second item of recyclerview with previous and next item visible]

I managed to do it by setting the width of the adapter to a static value and adding a padding to start and end of the recyclerview but, It doesn't scale on smaller/larger screen devices since the adapter's width is static. Any idea on how I can implement this while supporting different screen sizes? Or any library I can use to achieve this?
 Thank you

Comment: Did you able to achieve this?

Comment: @Manikanta was able to achieve something like this by modifying the recyclerview item's layout params in `onCreateViewHolder()` I got this one on mine 
`int itemWidth = screenWidth - (marginToSubtract * 2);
  
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(itemWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
  
    view.setLayoutParams(params);`
But I think you have to play with recyclerviews padding too and set `clipToPadding=false` to achieve that look on the first item,

Comment: thanks for your help, able to acheive that ( more or less in the same way) and made it as a wrapper recyclerview & adapter for reusability.

Comment: @Manikanta glad I could help, you're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You can center the item by adding the snaphelper to recycler view

```
//to center item of recyclerview when scrolling it.
        SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerview);
```